# source clear BUG in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 (v3.20). What I want to achieve is just to remove all features from a particular layer. I see that there is a [clear](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear) method and documentation says, that

> clear(opt_fast)
>
> Remove all features from the source.

However, when I apply it to my layer source like so:

```
layer.getSource().clear();
```

I see a blink (features are removed) and then I see a server request, so that features are reloaded again. So, either documentation is incomplete, or there is a bug.

I also tried to remove features like so:

```
features = source.getFeatures();
for (i = 0; i < features.length; i += 1) {
    source.removeFeature(features[i]);
}
```

But it works really strange. If, for example, I have four features, when I loop once, it removes just two features and when I loop twice, one extra feature is removed. All in all, I have to loop three times (which is indeed not DRY) to remove all features. I really wonder, why is that and how can I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: When you look over the features by index and remove number 1 then number 2 becomes the new number 1. So for each you remove you skip one, ie only half of them are removed. To get around this, reverse the loop and do `for(var i = features.length -1; i >= 0; i--)` instead.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren. Good advise! Thank you sir!

Comment: `layer.clear()` triggers the map layer to reload after it is cleared. A way around this is to use a vector loader function which can bypass a reload if you set a flag when using `.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Karl-Johan Sjögren, removing a array member when iterate through it modifies the array itself, so, you use reverse array or use a native function from Array [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
features = source.getFeatures();
features.forEach(function (feature){
  source.removeFeature(feature);
});
```